# How to change name of array in PHP using a POST result

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Suppose I have 2 arrays $test24 and $test48 . 
Now if I receive a web form POST $type value 24 I need to execute this

```
foreach ($test24 as $val) 
{
code here
}
```

while if I receive a web form POST $type value 48 I need to execute this

```
foreach ($test48 as $val) 
{
code here
}
```

I am trying to aggregate/merge the code above in a single foreach in this way

```
foreach ($test$type as $val) 
{
 code here
}
```

or this

```
foreach ($test.$type as $val) 
{
code here
}
```

but none of these two solutions works , do you know a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format of variable for your case is:

```
foreach (${'test' . $type} as $val)
```

But I advise you to use array instead of two variables:

```
$test = [24 => [1,2,3], 48 => [4,5,6]];


foreach ($test[$type] as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```